# Call a specific function in a contract at a specific block

Tags: web3js, presale

First of all I just started to tip my toes into smart contact development, so sorry if my question is not properly asked.

I want to participate in a pre-sale and to ensure my place I want to call the buy method of the contract at the block when the pre-sale starts. I found this:

`myContract.methods.methodName().call(transactionObject, blockNumber, callback)`

1. Is this the way to do it with web3.js?
2. Is it enough just to run a node server locally and put this function into a while loop?
3. Am I right that the callback doesn't matter in this case?

Any resource to help me out is welcomed.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myContract.methods.methodName().call(transactionObject, blockNumber, callback)
```

No, it is not the way to do it. The block number in RPC methods is meant for historic purposes only, not to execute functions in the future.

What you need to do is to monitor the network, and when the `block_number-1` will be announced, send your transaction expecting that on the next block (which is your desired `block_number`) it will be included. If you use high gas price it will be. But there is no guarantee as the block can be mined faster than your transaction propagating in the network. Because to propagate the `block_number-1` there will be also some delay. Try to increase `--maxpeers` to 500 or around that so your node has more connections and gets more updated data.